# RDLC report how to create multiple?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Suppose that you have a report  CustomerReport.rdlc which is for one customer....
Is it possible to have multiple customers reports in the same reportviewer?
If not  what is another solution ?

Comment: why the "crystal-reports" tag? reportviewer and .rdlc are not Crystal and they are not interoperable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution seems to be code generated rdlc!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to have one report for all customers. Basically you define your report template CustomerReport.rdlc to get data from some dataset (a stored procedure or some method in your datalayer).

for ex. your method should look something like this:

```
public DataTable GetCustomerDetails(int customerID)
{
    //call stored procedure
}
```

Then on the page where is ReportViewer you do something like this:

```
DataTable data = GetCustomerDetails(1);
this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "CustomerReport.rdlc";
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("[Datasource name defined in CustomerReport.rdlc]", data));
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response... I didnt understand how to to do it.. It does get data from dataset.Calling refresh would erase previous report.. I would like each customer have a page in report viewer so to be possible to print all of them or to export all of them..

Answer (score 0):

A single reportviewer control will show a single .rdlc document, along with any subreports included in the "parent" .rdlc "at a time". If you working in web forms it is also a best practice to not attempt to 'reload' a second report into a report viewer. It is better to empty the div containing the reportviewer and creating a new instance of the reportviewer control and insert that into the container (div/span/etc.)

After that it is just a matter of making sure you have the customer specific data assigned as the datasource.